# objective-c detect if class is available for different OS versions

Tags: objective-c, class, version, compatibility

My app needs to be compatible with different OS versions.

**How do I detect if a specific class is available to use with the particular OS?**

As an example, `NSPopover` is only available in Lion and up, so how can I check if the OS supports `NSPopover` in case the person is using Snow Leopard?

Comment: Look at the answers here and then see if you need to change your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406645/building-a-backwards-compatible-os-x-app-when-a-new-api-is-present

Comment: @JamesBlack what is the difference between "Base SDK" and "Deployment SDK", as I read about in the link? Where do I set these in Xcode 4? The only options I see are "OS X Deployment Target" under "Project", and "Deployment Target" under "Target" in Xcode. Difference?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You could do

```
if ([TheWantedClass class]) {
    // The class exists so run code
} else {
    // The class doesn't exist so use an alternate approach
}
```

or

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"TheWantedClass") != nil) {
    // The class exists
} else {
    // The class doesn't exist
}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring

Comment: Thank you, I think that second method would be best :)

Comment: I don't think the first method will compile if the class doesn't exist.

Comment: @Sabobin thats more for apple classes to check if they exist for the OS you are currently on. IE 6 vs 7