# Avoid adding NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification in OS version prior Lion(On Leopard or Snow Leopard)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsnotificationcenter

How can I avoid adding NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification in OS version prior to 10.7  because it is only available in OS 10.7 or above and I want to use this notification in above 10.7 but my application got crashed if I run it on prior OS version.
I have check the crash log and it was saying that
Symbol not found NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification

Right now I am checking the OS version using this

```
   if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_5) {
    /* On a 10.5.x or earlier system */
}
else if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_6) {
    /* On a 10.6 - 10.6.x system */
}  else  {
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(willEnterFull:)
                                                 name:NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification
                                               object:nil];





    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(didExitFull:)
                                                 name:NSWindowDidExitFullScreenNotification
                                               object:nil];
    }
```

But app got crashed in prior version as soon as it get launched.

Here is the crash log although I have change the app name to XYZ in the log due to NDA

```
Process:         XYZ [53319]
Path:            /Applications/XYZ.app/Contents/MacOS/XYZ
Identifier:      com.XYZ.XYZ
Version:         2.0.5 (2.0.5)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [224]

Date/Time:       2012-10-28 07:44:11.717 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _NSWindowDidExitFullScreenNotification
  Referenced from: /Applications/XYZ.app/Contents/MacOS/XYZ
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
 in /Applications/XYZ.app/Contents/MacOS/XYZ
```

Comment: Where does it crash? What's in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I *think* happens. The crash happens already in the linker, because it expects `NSWindowDidExitFullScreenNotification` to exist, but it doesn't in older versions of os x.

I haven't got any experience in this. The solutions seem to be kind of hacky.

Have a look at this question, where someone has an almost exact same question:
[How to build a backwards compatible OS X app, when a new API is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406645/building-a-backwards-compatible-os-x-app-when-a-new-api-is-present)

Comment: I am already setting the deployment target to 10.4 and base sdk to 10.8 as it is suggested in accepted answer in the above link.

Comment: Scholly Can we set AppKit framework as a weak/optional framework as suggested in the another answer in that link because NSWindowWillEnterFullScreenNotification lies in this framework?
Because I am new on OSx and does not have enough knowledge about this

Comment: @prakhar: Have you tried just setting the deployment target to 10.5? This should (according to some googling) weak-link the newer APIs.

Comment: Scholly no I haven't tried that right now my deployment target is 10.4 and base sdk is 10.8.
Do you want to say that the concept of weak link started from 10.5 or it should also applicable on 10.4

Comment: Scholly Thanks man its work for me, I have set the AppKit Framework as optional and here we go its works absolutely fine.
Once again thanks a lot.